# PostgreSQL - Query in Terminal - no output?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Im new in postgreSQL and db generally.

I connect to my database with

```
\c mydb
```

Its successfully - then I want to show all data from this table, I use

```
mydb-# SELECT * FROM mytable
```

It seems that this command works (no error), but I dont get an output?

Any ideas?

Comment: silly question did you put a semicolon in the end? `SELECT * FROM mytable ;`

Comment: Nevermind - I think thats the solution. I wrote like FROM mytable; instead of FROM mytable ;